# Having problems installing PHP GTK on a Mac running OS X 10.7.5

Tags: php-gtk

A colleague and I are attempting to install PHP GTK on a Mac running OS X 10.7.5.  When we try to install phpize, which is necessary for PHP GTK to run, we get the following error message:

> `lib-mug182:php-gtk vika$ sudo ./buildconf --with-phpize=/usr/bin/phpize
>      Password:
>      Configuring for:
>      PHP Api Version:         20090626
>      Zend Module Api No:      20090626
>      Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
>      rebuilding aclocal.m4
>      rebuilding configure
>      make[1]: autoconf: No such file or directory
>      make[1]: *** [configure] Error 1
>      make: *** [all] Error 2`

It looks like it cannot find autoconf. I am not familiar with Macs, so I'm not sure how to proceed at this point.

We have tried to follow instructions on the PHP GTK website specific to installing php gtk on a Mac (available at http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.installation.macosx.php
and 
http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.installation.macosx-stepbystep.php    ) and have gotten to this point in the directions where we got stuck:

```
   >Step 7 - Getting PHP-GTK2
```

>

> Instead of using current CVS, you might want to use the latest official version from the >PHP-GTK2 download page.
>
> Leave X11 open to be on the safe side. phpize and php-config should be both in /opt/local
>   /bin/. Check that before you run this. In Terminal, type:
>
> `sudo cvs -d :pserver:cvsread@cvs.php.net:/repository co php-gtk
>      cd php-gtk
>      sudo ./buildconf --with-phpize=/opt/local/bin/phpize
>      sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/local/bin/php-config
>      sudo make
>      sudo make install`

Thanks for any suggestions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this installer. It is in portuguese, but it is easy to translate:

http://www.php-gtk.com.br/mac